# Use next origin in case first origin returns error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to configure Cloudfront so first it looks for an object in S3 bucket and if it doesn't exist in the S3 bucket Cloudfront will use the next origin, which is Load Balancer, to retrieve the file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible using new origin Failover feature of CloudFront.
You can allow CloudFront to have List bucket access on S3 bucket so S3 can return 404 status code and you can choose to contact ELB if 404 occurs from S3.

Secondly, you can leverage lambda@edge Origin response function to make connection to ELB in case S3 returns 404 error.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-and-origin-failover.html